# For_each and pointer to member function

Tags: c++, stl

I came across a problem with the following code:

```
#include <list>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
using namespace std;

struct Person {
    string name;
    ostream& print(ostream& out) const {
        return out << name;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Person p = { "Mark" };
    list<Person> l;
    l.push_back(p);
    for_each(l.begin(), l.end(), bind(&Person::print, std::placeholders::_1, std::cout)); // this placeholder is not a pointer so it can't work anyways

    // I also tried something with lambdas like this but it doesn't work either
    //for_each(l.begin(), l.end(), bind([](Person& p, ostream& out) { mem_fun(&Person::print)(&p, out); }, std::placeholders::_1, cout));

    // it doesn't even work that way
    //for_each(l.begin(), l.end(), bind([](Person& p, ostream& out) { p.print(out); }, std::placeholders::_1, cout));
}
```

Here's an error message (in every case)

```
microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\tuple(80): error C2248: 'std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>>::basic_ostream' : cannot access protected member declared in class 'std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>>'
```

I want to know what's under the hood and why doesn't it work. What *protected* member is it talking about?

Comment: Any reason you need to use `bind` at all and can't just use a lambda: `[](const Person& p){p.print(cout);}`? In fact in these circumstances I find a ranged based for loop is more concise than a `for_each`: `for(const auto& p : l) p.print(cout); }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `for_each` call (and the associated `bind`) is trying to copy `std::cout` (regardless that `print` itself takes a reference) which is impossible since streams are non-copyable.

In C++03, the only way to enforce their non-copyability was to declare their copy constructor as `protected` (or `private`), hence the error you're seeing.

**Pass [`std::ref`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/ref)`(std::cout)` instead.**

Comment: Thank you so much, that pretty much solves the problem, but I have another question, now even this for_each works (for_each(l.begin(), l.end(), bind(&Person::print, std::placeholders::_1, std::cout));) But why? The placeholder is replaced by an object, not a pointer, isn't it?

Comment: @greenshade: That's the same call as in your question, and you said it _didn't_ work. Which is it? Anyway, if you have another question, post another question! :)

Comment: Yes, but I mean dereferencing an iterator would return an object, not a pointer to an object so after passing to &Person::print as the first argument should be an error? Or not? :)

Comment: @greenshade: I don't understand what you're asking. What iterator?

Comment: While iterating through a list for_each uses iterators. I am talking about this iterator.

Comment: @greenshade: `std::bind()` is designed to correctly invoke the member function even if the argument passed to it is a (reference to) an object. See, for instance, here: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/19b3f7bafa87a92f

Comment: Thank you @LightnessRacesinOrbit :) It's clear to me now

Answer (score 3):

You need to use [`std::ref`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/ref) if you want `std::cout` to be passed by reference to the `print()` function. Otherwise, a copy of it will be attempted, because `std::for_each` takes its functor argument by value, and the type of `std::cout` is not copyable:<sup>1</sup>

```
for_each(l.begin(), 
         l.end(), 
         bind(&Person::print, std::placeholders::_1,  std::ref(std::cout));
//                                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

<kbd>[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a688d26947464c4e)</kbd>

---

<sup>1</sup> The message you're seeing about a `protected` copy-constructor being inaccessible is due to the fact that in the implementation of the Standard Library you are using, non-copyability is achieved by making the class's copy-constructor non-`public`. This was the only way to realize non-copyability in C++03 - since C++11, the idiomatic way is to define the copy-constructor as *deleted*.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that the `std::bind` expression will result in copies of its arguments being made. `std::cout` is not from a copyable type, hence the error. You can fix this by passing an `std::reference_wrapper` instead. You can make one of those by using `std::ref`:

```
for_each(l.begin(), l.end(), 
         bind(&Person::print, std::placeholders::_1, std::ref(std::cout)));
                                                     ^^^^^^^^
```